# Does Notification Service Extension require separate provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification

I am working since days on this problem. I need to show Image in notification. For which I created Notification Service Extension and Notification Content Extension.
But It shows this:
[Error in Service Signing and Capabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJRir.png)
[Error in Content Signing and Capabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sabVh.png)

And I am not able to create archive.
Please Help I am really struggling with this.
App works fine but not able to create archive because of "Service has conflicting provisioning settings. Service is automatically signed, but provisioning profile Automatic has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the Signing & Capabilities editor." and "code signing is required for product type 'App Extension' in SDK 'iOS 13.6'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved it:**
Solution was simpler then I thought it would be GOTO build Settings of the target that was giving the issue. Then type "provisioning" in search in User defined PROVISIONING PROFILE make the field blank i.e. Automatic was written just remove anything that is written.
Error got solved..

Comment: While archiving the app for distribution, you would be needing provisioning profiles for all the targets (App Target and notification extension target) . Also, Each target or provisioning profile signing certificate should be same.

Comment: @AnmolSuneja no need to archive all targets just app target.

Comment: If I remove provisioning profile from Notification service extension, I got error provisioning  profile needed for NotificationService and not able to archive the app target because notification service is embed in app target

Comment: hey, don't remove provisioning profile just remove anything that is written.

Answer (score 0):

.Close Xcode project
.Using finder go to project folder
.Right click on .xcodeproj and choose "Show Package Contents"
.Right click on project.pbxproj go on "Open With" and choose TextEdit
.Now search for your Provision Profile instanceId specified in the error message.
.Delete all found texts and let Provisioning Profiles clean.
.Save & Close
.Open Xcode
.Enable automatically manage signing